# javascript loop needed to show hidden list onclick one at a time

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I have a list of hidden divs and would like to be able to show one div at a time, when a button is pressed, .. I am having a hard time writing the proper loop for this.

```
product_options: function() {
        var product_option = $('.product_product_options_option_name')
        $(product_option).css("display", "none");
        $('.add_product_option').on('click', function (e) {
             e.preventDefault();  
             $(product_option).each(function(){
                 $(this).css("display", "block")
             });
        });
    }
```

currently it displays them all onclick, i deleted all my other loop attempts, bc they were egregiously wrong or were not doing much

Comment: should be $(this).show()

Comment: When you say one at a time, do you mean one click on add_product_option would show 1 div, or a div would show and then a delay, then another div would show?

Comment: You should append your div in a container with jQuery.

Comment: i mean one click on div shows thanks for asking for the clarification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
product_option.first().show(); //show only the first one
product_option = product_option.slice(1); //remove the first one
```

**Demo:**

```js
$(function() {
  var options = $('.product_option').hide();
  
  $('.add').click(function() {
    if(options.length) {
      options.first().show();
      options = options.slice(1);      
    }
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="product_option">Option 1</div>
<div class="product_option">Option 2</div>
<div class="product_option">Option 3</div>
<div class="product_option">Option 4</div>
<div class="product_option">Option 5</div>
<div class="product_option">Option 6</div>
<div class="add">Add product option</div>
```

Comment: I need a similar feature but I only want one thing to display at the time. so if I click add product Option 2 will show but not option 1, then if I click again option 3 will show and not the two option preceding this one.

Comment: @Cyzanfar You could simply maintain current option http://jsfiddle.net/tarabyte/t10qtytx/

Answer (score 0):

```js
product_options: function() {
  var product_option = $('.product_product_options_option_name')
  $(product_option).css("display", "none");
  $('.add_product_option').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();  
    $(product_option + ':hidden').eq(0).show();
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this : [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3eLvajkL/1/)

```js
$('.product_product_options_option_name').hide();

var count = 0;
$('.add_product_option').on('click',function(){
    $('.product_product_options_option_name:eq('+count+')').show();
    count++;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="add">
    <input type="button" class="add_product_option" value="click" />
</div>
<div class="product_product_options_option_name">
    <label>1div</label>
</div>
<div class="product_product_options_option_name">
    <label>2div</label>
</div>
<div class="product_product_options_option_name">
    <label>3div</label>
</div>
<div class="product_product_options_option_name">
    <label>4div</label>
</div>
```